# How to reuse the same WebDriver in different application using selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

i'm writing here to ask if is possible to init `WebDriver`

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

and use the same browser for many jar application, so doing, in other jar file, something like:

```
int port = ...;
String host = ...;
WebDriver driver = getDriver(host,port);
```

i ask this question because FirefoxDriver is very slow to load and happear, and i need to call many jar that load that driver. i think that in this way, loading just one time my driver, my total application will be fastly than open N-times N-instances of that driver. i hope that my question is clear and well-formed :) thanks to all!

EDIT:
i see that there is the possibility to use `RemoteWebDriver`.

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
```

How can i use it? when i have to instantiate the webdriver in localhost:4444?

Comment: Using the pageobject design pattern, I believe people usually pass around the instance of WebDriver from page to page and therefore don't need to reuse the browser.  For a while I was extending FirefoxDriver and overriding methods to force the re-use of a browser, which worked for a while but then it broke again around build 2.17 or so and I haven't got it to work since then.

Answer (score 1):

This is [the most demanded feature request in Selenium](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=18). However, it's still not possible to attach a `WebDriver` to running browser window. What you discovered in `RemoteWebDriver` is the posibility to run tests remotely on another computer. But that computer still has to start a new browser window.

You could, I guess, write your application as something as a HUB that would enqueue all jars (classes) to run, would start a single instance of Firefox and pass the `driver` reference around. It's not a nice solution and as far as I know, nobody has done it yet.

BUT! The majority of time spent on startup in Firefox is creating a new [`FirefoxProfile`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.html). If you created one profile dedicated to testing and started your Firefox always with this profile, it would be significantly faster.

Comment: how can i create a firefoxprofile and attach to every webdriver?

Comment: Get any profile. Even a clean one. They are stored at `%APPDATA%/Mozilla/Mozilla Firefox/profiles` or `%TEMP%` (there are temp profiles from WebDriver). Store the folder anywhere. [Instantiate FirefoxDriver with that Profile](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver.html#FirefoxDriver%28org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile%29).